# Finding the difference between two arrays in FSharp

Tags: f#

I have two arrays where I want to find the elements from the second array that are not in the first array.

I wrote the following code:

```
let array0 = [|"A";"B";"C"|]
let array1 = [|"B";"D";"E"|]

let inZero letter = 
    array0 |> Array.tryFind(fun l -> if l = letter then true else false)

array1|> Array.filter(fun l -> inZero(l).IsSome)
```

But I am wondering if there is something that is more idiomatic to FSharp.

Thanks in advance

Comment: Aside, the now deleted answer which suggested using `Enumerable.Except` sounded like a good option too.

Comment: If you're prepared to wait until F# 4.0 (or possibly 4.1) there's a pull request open for Array.Except :) https://github.com/Microsoft/visualfsharp/pull/253

Answer (score 6, accepted):

If you do not care about duplicates, then you could write this using F# sets:

```
// Elements that are in array1, but not in array0
set array1 - set array0

// Elements that are in both arrays (which is what your sample returns)
Set.intersect (set array1) (set array0)
```

In both cases, you get back a new `set<int>`, which is also a `seq<int>`, so you can iterate over it or turn it back into array using `Array.ofSeq`.

If you want to keep duplicates (if there are duplicates in `array1`, then return the element multiple times), then I think what you have is good. If you wanted to compare *multiple* arrays against one, then it would make sense to turn `array0` into a dictionary for more efficient lookup:

```
let inZero =
  let set0 = set array0
  set0.Contains

// Elements from array1 that are also in array0 (returns multiple
// copies of the same element if it appears repeatedly in array1)
array1 |> Array.filter inZero
```

The conversion to set has some cost, but it reduces the lookup time. So, depending on how you use this & what is the size of the arrays, this will have different performance characteristics. But the code looks nicer, so this would be my default choice.

Comment: I meant to do .IsNone so return what is not in both.  Do a not Set.intersect?

Comment: The set difference (`set array1 - set array0`) should give you elements that are in `array1`, but not in `array0` (the intersection does what your code did with `IsSome`)