# F# Threading a result of a function through Array.Reduce

Tags: f#

As a followup to [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28682141/finding-the-difference-between-two-arrays-in-fsharp?noredirect=1#comment45657971_28682141) question, I have a function that returns an array comprised of an input array and then some other elements calculated in the function.

I want to use a high order function to call this function multiple times, each time threading the result array of the prior function call into the next functional call.  I believe that array.map is the best choice here, but I am not sure.  This is what I have so far (note the last line does not compile):

```
let myFunction (index:int, allLetters: string[]) =
    let computedArray = [|"A";"B";"D"|]
    Array.append allLetters computedArray

let allLetters = [||]
[|1..10|] |> Array.reduce(fun acc -> myFunction(acc,allLetters))
```

Am I on the right track?

Here is a picture of what I want to accomplish:
[image]

I want to pass the array into the next function with the index
(int;string[]) and I want to return a string[].  That return I want to pass with a new index into the next function.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: `Array.fold`? `Array.scan`? It's not clear to me what you're trying to achieve. Can you share some input data and expected output?

Comment: Added a picture in the original question.  Does that help?

Comment: Sorry, that doesn't help much. Where does the "E" in the fifth sample come from?

Comment: "E" is generated by the function being called

Answer (score 0):

I don't understand exactly what you want to achieve, please clarify. So it's hard to come up with a sample code, anyway from what I understood:

`Array.map` doesn't seem to be helpful here, since each function application is independent for each element of the array, but you need to thread an accumulator.

`Array.fold` is probably what you're looking for. It computes a function between all array elements threading the result of the previous function application. You need to specify an initial state for the accumulator.

`Array.reduce` is just a special fold where the first element of the array is used as the initial state (accumulator), of course if the Array is empty it will fail.

Comment: Added a picture in the original question.  Does that help?

Comment: Thanks, but how is possible given the same inputs (case 3 and 4) that you expect different outputs?

Comment: Side-effect programming. :-)

Answer (score 0):

If you look at [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee340509.aspx), here is the example for reduce:

```
let names = [| "A"; "man"; "landed"; "on"; "the"; "moon" |]
let sentence = names |> Array.reduce (fun acc item -> acc + " " + item)
```

I then added a function that the lambda calls:

```
let firstLetter (s:System.String) = s.Substring(0,1)
let names = [| "A"; "man"; "landed"; "on"; "the"; "moon" |]
let sentence = names |> Array.reduce (fun acc item -> acc + " " + firstLetter(item))
```

I then added a second parameter to the firstLetter function:

```
let firstLetter (s:System.String, s':System.String) = s.Substring(0,1)
let names = [| "A"; "man"; "landed"; "on"; "the"; "moon" |]
let sentence = names |> Array.reduce (fun acc item -> acc + " " + firstLetter(item, acc))
```

Finally, I changed the return from the firstLetter function to be a tuple:

```
let firstLetter (s:System.String, s':System.String) = s.Length, s.Substring(0,1)
let names = [| "A"; "man"; "landed"; "on"; "the"; "moon" |]
let sentence = names |> Array.reduce (fun acc item -> acc + " " + firstLetter(item, acc))
```

The compiler does not like that:

> The type 'int * string' does not match the type 'string'

So it looks like the reduce accumulator needs to be the same type as the type in the array what is getting reduce applied to?

Comment: Yes, the types should be the same. With folds you have a bit more flexibility since the type of the accumulator may be something else. Please next time send me a message, because I don't get notified if you write your question as an answer.