# F# find all elements present in another array

Tags: f#

this solution

```
d1 |> Array.filter (fun t -> d2 |> Array.exists (fun t2 -> t=t2))
```

from this so answer

[Finding the difference between two arrays in FSharp](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28682141/finding-the-difference-between-two-arrays-in-fsharp)

gives this error

```
Severity    Code    Description Project File    Line    Suppression State
Error       Type mismatch. Expecting a
    unit -> bool    
but given a
    'a [] -> bool    
The type 'unit' does not match the type ''a []' ParseLibs   
Program.fs  25
```

Full code:

```
// Learn more about F# at http://fsharp.org
// See the 'F# Tutorial' project for more help.

open System
open System.IO

open FSharp.Collections

[<EntryPoint>]
let main argv = 
    let path = "data1.txt"
    let lines = use reader = new StreamReader(path) in reader.ReadToEnd().Split('\n')
    let n = 5

    let d1 = lines 
            |> Array.takeWhile (fun e -> not (e.Equals "\r")) 

    let d2 = lines 
            |> Array.skipWhile (fun e -> not (e.Equals "\r")) 
            |> Array.skip 1
            |> Array.mapi (fun i e -> e, i)
            |> Array.filter (fun (e, i) -> i % n = 0)
            |> Array.iter (fun (e, i) -> printfn "%s" e)

    d1 |> Array.filter (fun t -> d2 |> Array.exists (fun t2 -> t=t2))

    //let writer = new StreamWriter(path)

    ignore (Console.ReadKey())
    0 // return an integer exit code
```

Is the answer there wrong? What is the real answer? I am simply trying to filter all the elements that are in both arrays. In most functional languages this is as trivial as they come.

```
d1 |> Array.filter (fun t -> d2.contains(t))
```

Comment: You are in fact using the question of the link, and NOT the answer. If you want the intersection (the elements in d1 and d2) then you need to read the answer and the comments, Not the question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The problem is that `d2` has type unit.

As `array.iter` returns `()`

I would change to

```
let d2 = lines 
        |> Array.skipWhile (fun e -> not (e.Equals "\r")) 
        |> Array.skip 1
        |> Array.mapi (fun i e -> e, i)
        |> Array.filter (fun (e, i) -> i % n = 0)

d1 
|> Array.filter (fun t -> d2 |> Array.exists (fun t2 -> t=t2)) 
|> Array.iter (fun (e, i) -> printfn "%s" e)
```

Comment: I'm not asking about that line. The first piece of code I posted has the error.

Comment: But that is where the error comes from - unit does not match `'a[]`

Comment: Your solution is to print all the elements in the array for some reason. Im looking for all elements contained in both.

Comment: changed it a little

Comment: @JohnPalmer  And some nit picking: The "real answer" is http://stackoverflow.com/a/28682277/5514938 which is the answer of the linked question.

Answer (score 0):

Using the actual answer from the above link: https://stackoverflow.com/a/28682277/5514938 and adding the information at https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Set_theory#Basic_concepts_and_notation
the following code is an example of the three first concepts with same sets/values as in wiki article.

```
let d1= [|"1";"2";"3";|] //pretend this to be the filtered/skipped/mapped
                         //whatever but otherwise "clean" structure/datatypes
let d2 = [|"2";"3";"4";|] //pretend this to be the filtered/skipped/mapped
                          //whatever  but otherwise "clean" structure/datatypes 
                          //equal to d1


let s1 = d1 
        |> Set.ofArray

let s2 = d2 
        |> Set.ofArray


let all = s1 + s2 //Union
let inBoth = Set.intersect s1 s2 //Intersection

let onlyIn_d1 = s1 - s2 //Set difference
let onlyIn_d2 = s2 - s1 //Set difference the other way ;-)
```

I have removed your other code to simplify the concepts, so the initial filter, skippings and mappings you are doing must of course be done ahead of the above code. And you must also "realign" the types to be equal again:

```
|> Array.mapi (fun i e -> e, i)
|> Array.filter (fun (e, i) -> i % n = 0)
|> Array.map (fun (e,i) -> e)
|> Set.ofArray
```